# Calling another view from an action in Zend Framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have downloaded a sample ZF2 project from github and configured in my system. I am not able to understand the routing system that how they called a view from an action and what should I do to call some other view(`b.phtml`) from the `aAction` function in my controller

In my `WWW`
`url_shortner\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php` is my index controller

In my `IndexController.php` my index function is like this

```
public function indexAction()
{ 
}
```

the function is empty one and there is a view file in

```
url_shortner\module\Application\view\application\index\index.phtml
```

There is no calling of `index.phtml` in index function But still the `index.phtml` file is loading. I want to know how they routed this. Where we need to tell the function to call the particular view file. Someother day, I want to call `xyz.phtml` from some `BlaBla function` in the `controller` where the `function name` and the `view file name` are `different`, how can I do that.

If you want any other code to put, please ask me. I will place the code here
I am really struggling with this. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default view location if you define nothing in your controller

> url_shortener/module/MyModuleName/view/my-module-name/view/CONTROLLER_NAME/ACTION_NAME.phtml

You can change your view this way:

```
public function indexAction(){
    $view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $view ->setTemplate('your-module/your-controller/your-view'); //without .phtml
    return $view
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this... If my folder structure is `url_shortner\module\Api\src\Api\Controller\ApiController.php` is another controller and  `url_shortner\module\Api\view\api\api\test.phtml` is a view. As you said above please tell me how to call test.phtml from `url_shortner\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php` indexAction function

Comment: Be sure that ZF2 knows that path (see config view_manager -> template_path_stack or template_map) and then it should work. If you follow the ZF2 documentation than the module / controller / view name order should be like in the manual http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html